# mssql isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm following this guide. [Mssql-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django) and I have Django version 3.2.12
I already installed mssql-django 1.1.1
I also have pyodbc 4.0.32

modified my settings.py to have

```
'ENGINE': 'mssql',
```

But im still receving this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mssql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one 
of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: did you have installed `pyodbc >= 3.0`?

Comment: yes @ellhe-blaster I have 4.0.32 version

Comment: Are you sure that right env is used?

Comment: @Cadz How are you running the project? Tried to install same versions and it works fine

Comment: did you install [microsoft ODBC driver for sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Flask. The solution was the following:

1. Create a file named `odbcinst.ini` with contents

> ```
> [FreeTDS]
> Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
> ```

2. The `requirements.txt` file should have a working version of mssql and pyodbc.

For example :

```
mssql==1.0.1
pyodbc==4.0.31
```

3. And the server configuration has:

   ```
   SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
   'my_database': "mssql+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}?driver=FreeTDS".format(
       os.getenv("database_user"), 
       os.getenv("database_password"), 
       os.getenv("database_host")
   )
   ```

   }
4. And finally the `Dockerfile` could be something like this:

   > ```
   >  FROM python:3.9.8-slim
   >
   >  [...other staff here...]
   >
   >  COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/
   >
   >  [...other staff here...]
   > ```

Hopefully, you will be able to transform the flask idioms into your django application and make it work. This gave me quite a frustration while I was trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```py
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Installed **unixodbc-dev**

```py
pip install pyodbc
pip install mssql-django
```

but now i have other problem

```sh
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

and with no idea how to solve it, I already installed driver 17. It just can't find it

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31808995)